# Is it possible to embed a checkbox in a grid using Salt

Tags: plantuml

I am building a wireframe for a future application and would like a grid with a checkbox column on the left. I am using the empty checkbox widget `[ ]` inside a table.

Here is my code:

```
@startuml

salt
{
    {#
        Col1|Col2
        [ ]|Row data
    }
}

@enduml
```

I am finding that the checkbox is [rendering as a button](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SoWkIImgAStDuU8gJimfuQhcugnMvkBaTCxFCQm14aP0ThH2R4rGVhb2Ic998XTdBLSj5vT3QbuAK1C0). Is there a way to get this to render as an empty checkbox?

**Update:**

I have come up with a work around that takes advantage of the UTF-8 characters U+2610 and U+2612. This more or less gives me what I am after, but I'll leave the question open for a few days in case someone has an actual solution.

```
@startuml

salt
{
    {#
        Col1|Col2
        ☐|Row data
        ☒|Row data
    }
}

@enduml
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another workaround

```
@startuml
salt
{
    {#
        Col1|Col2|*
        [ ]⠀| Row data
        [x]⠀| Row data
    }
}
@enduml
```

[it's not visible at the plain eye](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SoWkIImgAStDuIfEp2dXgkRYh5RcukHqpiynh04IHZLQG5wqGkoZ1Gqr2a7vvGefYIM98A4ATA5QhbekXzIy5A1P0000) but since to be recognized as textbox it needs some text in front of the `[]` I added UTF character U+2800 that is a blank space.

[image: visual result]